# Keras lambda layer wrong output size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have 2 inputs into a lambda layer one size (2,3,) the other (3,) . The lambda layer should return an output of size 2, however when the multiply layer is executed the following error occurs:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 3 for 'multiply_1/mul' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [?,2], [?,3].

The relevant code is below and any help would be much appreciated,thanks:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras.layers import Dense,Input,concatenate,Lambda,multiply,add
import tensorflow as tf
import time
def weights_Fx(x):
    j = x[0][:,0]
    k = x[1][0]
    y = j - k
    return y
def sum_layer(x):
    x = tf.reduce_sum(x)
    return x
type1_2 = Dense(units=1, activation = 'relu',name = "one")
type1_3 = Dense(units=1,activation = 'relu',name = "two")
in1 = Input(shape=(1,))
in2 = Input(shape=(1,))
n1 = type1_2(in1)
n2 = type1_3(in2)
model = concatenate([n1,n2],axis=-1,name='merge_predicitions')
coords_in = Input(shape=(2,3,))
coords_target = Input(shape=(3,))
model2 = Lambda(weights_Fx,output_shape=(2,),name='weightsFx')([coords_in,coords_target])
model = multiply([model,model2])
model = Lambda(sum_layer)(model)
model = Model(inputs=[in1,in2,coords_in,coords_target],outputs=[model])
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue was to do with how I was indexing the array. It is important to remember that though the data is of shape (2,3) keras will create a Tensor of shape (None,2,3) therefore to perform the operation as desired the following is needed:

```
y = x[0][:,:,0]-x[1][:,0]
```

Furthermore in "sum layer" in order to prevent the rank (number of dimensions) in the tensor being reduced by 1 the following is required:

```
y = K.sum(x,axis=1,keepdims=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Lambda` layer is not returning output of shape `2` but it is returning output of shape `3`.
Model2 shape is  `(,3)` and not `(,2)` which is giving error in multiply of the `model` and `model2`

Take a look at your `coords_in` and `coords_target` shape.

Comment: But the function weights_Fx only considers the first column of coords_in and given the shape is (2,3,) the shape of the output should be (2,).

Comment: weights_Fx is not returning tensor of shape (2,) but it returning tensor of shape (3,). Take a look at tensor slicing and tf.slice.